# How can i configure Mongoose to automatically create objects in my mongoDB on app start if none is found?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am coming from a Java  Hibernate frameworks, where an sql script can be written and added to a project, with the intentions of creating objects in my Mongo Database when the app runs and no data was found in a specific database table. I am using Mongoose presently with mongoDB, and i want to initialize my mongoDB table with objects if none is found. Initially i achieved this my creating an object and calling the new mongoose.save(obj) inside my app.js which is my start up file. But is there a cleaner way one already supported by Mongoose, or is this my best bet ?